# Hide category for not logged in users Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function, categories

How to hide certain categories from 'not logged in users' in Wordpress blog? And redirect these 'not logged in users' to the login screen, and after login back to the post page?

All posts from that private category should be hidden (over the entire blog) for not logged in users. No messages, just completely not visible.

I tried to add this code to the funcions.php:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
query_posts();
}
else{
query_posts( cat= -1 );
}
?>
```

But that shows a blank page on admin and front end.

Is there anybody who can help me how to do this? There should be a plugin for this, but there is none. Any help will be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Hi val, welcome to SO. Could you edit you're question and share what you've already tried? It will help give you an answer.

Comment: I tried to add this code to the funcions.php:

`<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
query_posts();
}
else{
query_posts( cat='-1 );
}
?>`

For redirecting to login I use a plugin now. I first wanted to try to hide a certain category for non logged in users.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a very simple conditional tag for to not display content if a user is not logged in:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
    echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
}
?>
```

This will work if you are editing your own template.

Otherwise [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-members/) is great.

To redirect users after log in use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/), also great!

Comment: Thank you Siegfried, but the plugin description says:

WP-Members does not automatically hide absolutely everything from view. The default install of the plugin is designed to use "teaser" content to drive users to want to register. If you want certain content or menu elements completely hidden, there are ways to do that with some customization between your theme and the plugin, but it is not automatic

Comment: I aim to simply hide the entire post for not logged in users. Just as if the post does not exist at all...the post url will redirect to the login, and after successful login redirect back to the post url (showing the post for user is logged in)

Answer (score 0):

Ah....it looks like the code is to put in the Loop, not in function.php. I will ask a new question about how to create a function that hides a certain category if user is not logged in. Thank you for your time and suggestions!